# How to customize API end points on redoc API documentation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, documentation, drf-yasg, redoc

I am using `redoc` in `django==2.0` for documenting some `django` API. I noticed that by default redoc will name the endpoints automatically as you can see on the image below on the left side. Most likely I don't want to use the names generated I want customize the names. From someone who has experience with `redoc` documentation could you advice please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `drf-yasg`, you can use the `swagger_auto_schema` decorator to configure the `operation_id`.

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(name='get', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(operation_id='List Widgets', operation_description='List all available widgets'))
class WidgetListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Widget.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

These summaries are actually populated from the input JSON, which can be found at this path in source `["paths"][path][method]["summary"]`.
You might want to edit these in order to change the summaries.
If you don't want to change the source input a hack around can be to change the text of DOM elements after REDOC load.